# How to randomly distribute N masses, such that they follow a Plummer density distribution in Python

Tags: python, physics

I am working in Python. I have `N` stars, each of one solar mass `M_0`. I want to randomly distribute these stars in a volume of radius `R`, such that the density distribution follows a [Plummer model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plummer_model), given by this formular:

[image]

I understand that `M` is the total cluster mass, in this case `M=NM_0`, but am unsure as to how I would code for this mass distribution.

Comment: There is not Python code in your question. Do you use any library? Show us your code.

Answer (score 5):

In what follows I'm going to assume that you are using `numpy` in python imported as

```
import numpy as np
```

The easiest way to do this is to work in spherical polar coordinates (r,θ,φ)

- x = r sin(θ) cos(φ)
- y = r sin(θ) sin(φ)
- z = r cos(θ)

You then need a way of selecting each of these in turn.

The angular coordinates are easiest so we can start with those. Here we want to pick the angles θ and φ so that they are uniformly distributed on the surface of a sphere.

## The Azimuthal Angle (φ)

As there is no additional factors in the area element this can just be chosen uniformly in the range [0,2π)

```
phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi)
```

## The Polar Angle (θ)

Here we need to chose this so that sin(θ)dθ is uniform note that we can write sin(θ)dθ = d(cos(θ)) so in other words for each value of θ that we pick cos(θ) needs to be equally likely. If we sample cos(θ) between [-1,1) then this will give the correct distribution of values of θ

```
theta = np.arccos( np.random.uniform(-1,1) )
```

## The Radius (r)

Now we have a way of distributing points randomly on the surface of a sphere we now need a way of knowing how the radii are distributed.

For this we need the cumulative mass distribution

[image]

which is the amount of mass enclosed at a radius r from the center of the Plummer sphere.

When we create a new star, and place it at radius r, that star
will see an amount of mass m(r) of the cluster at positions closer to the center than its own position, and therefore an amount of mass M − m(r) at positions further from the center.

In other words, it will see a fraction m(r)/M of the total mass inside its radial position. Now that fraction could be anything between 0 and 1. It will be 0 if the particle is placed exactly in the center, and it will approach 1 if the particle is placed very far away, reaching 1 when the particle is placed at infinity.

The ranking of each particle, in terms of the enclosed mass, is random and uniform in the mass fraction. In other words, m(r)/M will be a random value between 0 and 1, with each value equally likely.

To get an expression for the radius we thus need to invert m(r) to give us r(m) the radius where a fraction m of the mass will reside

[image]

Thus if we pick m uniform in [0,1) we can then use that equation to convert that into the correct radius.

```
r = a / np.sqrt( np.random.uniform(0, 1)**(-2.0 / 3.0) - 1)
```

Once your have those coordinates you can use the expressions I gave above to convert them back into cartesians.

That'll do it for one star, I'll leave it to you to figure out how to efficiently do it for n in python.

## References

I've based this answer pretty heavily on [The Art of Computational Science](http://www.artcompsci.org/kali/vol/plummer/volume11.pdf) also see this for how to assign velocities self consistantly from the Plummer distribution function.

The method I've described here can be found in the appendix of [Aarseth et. al. 1974](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1974A%26A....37..183A)

Comment: and how do we choose a value of a? I can see that its related to the size of the radius R. At r=R, is the density zero, which is how a is determined

Comment: The density goes to zero at infinity. You can either pick ``a`` by looking at the physical system you are modelling and setting the scale to be something reasonable for that.

Comment: So say I was modelling a system with a radius of scale ~10 parsecs, I would calculate 'a' based of the density going to zero at r=10 parsecs?

Comment: No the density of a plummer sphere is only zero at infinity. If by scale you mean a half-mass radius then you could use ``r_h = 1.3a`` (which can be got from the enclosed mass distribution I gave above) to set ``a`` based on that.

Comment: Sorry, by scale I mean that all of the masses I am interested in are contained within a sphere of radius ~10 pc. Is there a way to set a, such that we obtain a Plummer mass distribution, within a  radius of ~10pc?