# Sampling uniformly distributed random points inside a spherical volume using numpy arrays (PLOTLY)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plotly

I want to distribute 5k points in a homogeneous sphere of radius 100. I used the cumulative mass distribution [(integral here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434765/how-to-randomly-distribute-n-masses-such-that-they-follow-a-plummer-density-dis) to calculate the radius point value. But when I plotted the sphere, it has cumulative points in the vertical axis:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziTcO.png)

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from numpy import  sin, cos, pi, random, array

phi = random.uniform(0, 2 * pi,5000)
theta = random.uniform(0,pi,5000)
u = random.uniform(0, 1,5000)

r = array([0]*5000)
x = array([0]*5000)
y = array([0]*5000)
z = array([0]*5000)

for i in range(0,5000):
     r[i] = ( 100 * (u[i]) ** (1 / 3))

     x[i] = ( r[i] * sin(theta[i]) * cos(phi[i]))
     y[i] = ( r[i] * sin(theta[i]) * sin(phi[i]))
     z[i] = (r[i] * cos(theta[i]))


df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x = x, y = y, z=z, title='Distribuição de pontos em um esfera')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=1))
fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark',scene=dict(xaxis_title="Abscissa", yaxis_title="Ordenada", zaxis_title="Cota"))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were trying to base your approach on the linked method, you may have accidentally not noticed that `theta` was off.

```
from numpy import  sin, cos, pi, random, array, arccos

phi   = random.uniform(0, 2 * pi, 5000)
theta = arccos(random.uniform(-1, 1, 5000))
u     = random.uniform(0, 1, 5000)
```

That should work better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

nvm, the problem was that it was selecting random values from cos function that has a accumulation at y=0, therefore I needed to select the cos value (-1,1) as it follows

```
costheta = random.uniform(-1,1,5000)
theta = arccos(costheta)
```